# Navigator rebuilds both parent and destination pages inside Bottom navigation bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigator, rebuild

Whenever i push one page to another page inside **bottomNavigationBar**. Navigator rebuilds both parent and destination pages. Actually Only destination page should be rebuld.

How to **prevent** rebuild of parent page only?

Answer (score 0):

try using 
**AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** on your parent widget

Comment: Can you explain in details so i can implement easily?